# byte byCallData[] = {0x2} in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, byte, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

I'm converting code android to javascript for cordova application mobile. How can I write android instruction:

```
byte byCallData[] = {0x2};
```

in javascript?
I have tryed to use:

```
var mytry = new Uint8array([2]);
```

But it isn't the samething.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want a rough javascript equivalent you could use:

```
var byCallData = [0x2];
```

you just have to be careful about what operations you use on it and use the appropriate bit masks to clear the upper bits when necessary (i.e. `byCallData[0] &= 0xFF` will make sure the value is between 0 and 255 like an unsigned byte).
if you need the exact range of an android/java 'byte' (i.e. -127 to 128) then you can use an Int8Array

**Edit:** had mistake in constructor call(fixed now):

```
var byCallData = new Int8Array(1);
byCallData[0] = 0x2;
```